# Is there any 'Post-Aggregation' method in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to run some statistics on my cluster.

Sometimes it is impossible for me to retrieve all the documents in scope of one index (or one type) because its a huge traffic of data. So I put some limit (say: `"size": 1000`) on my query.

Combined with aggregation scope, I'm getting 1000 documents in the hits scope, and aggregation results for **all matching documents in the index**.

This behavior is understandable, but because of the nature of my statistics I would like to aggregate only on the actual retrieved documents.

I know there is a method called 'Post-Filtering' in the query scope which happen **after** the aggregation is calculated.

So, what I'm searching is some 'Post-Aggregation' which happen **after** the documents are retrieved, so the aggregation will be true only on those documents that were retrieved.

Here is some query example:

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "make": "ford"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above query, I would like to get aggregation results only on those 1000 retrieved documents.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get aggregation results only on those 1000 retrieved documents.

**Short answer:** use [Sampler aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html)

**Long answer:** you can get top *N* from each shard

---

Given your query:

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "make": "ford"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After adding Sampler aggregation will look like:

```
{
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "make": "ford"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "sample": {
            "sampler": {
                "shard_size": 200
            },
            "aggs": {
                "types": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "color"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note `"shard_size": 200` - default is 100. If you have 5 shards (default in ES) you'll get a total of 5 * 200 = 1000 results

Comment: Thank you Vlad. Doe's it have any correlation to the returned hits?

Comment: No, whatever you set in aggregation is separate from search hits.